# ActionMailer pass local variables to the erb template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, erb, local-variables

I know I could define instance variables e.g:

```
def user_register(username, email)
  @username = username
  @email = email

  mail(:to => email, :subject => "Welcome!", :template_name => "reg_#{I18n.locale}")
end
```

But, is there a way to use **local** variables instead, just like passing *:locals* to partials?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All options available in the `mail` method can be found at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail.

We know that `render` has a `:locals` option. However we can see that there is no `:locals` option available for `mail`. Therefore, no, there is no better way than to use instance variables (unless you want to use something hideous like globals or persistent database objects - **don't do this**).

Instance variables are what you are meant to use.

Comment: OK. Thanks! Will use them then!

Answer (score 29):

As ronalchn pointed out, it's the `render` that has `:locals`, not the `mail` method. So, you need a direct access to the `render` method in order to pass the locals.

You can give a block to the `mail` and that way gain access to the `render` method, something like this:

```
mail(to: "your_mail@example.com", subject: "Test passing locals to view from mailer") do |format|
  format.html {
    render locals: { recipient_name: "John D." }
  }
end
```

And now you should be able to use `"Hello <%= recipient_name %>"`

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 5, you simply have to define instance variables using `@` in your method. You no longer have access to the `locals` property for this purpose.

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def welcome_email(user_id:, to_email:, user_full_name:, token:)    
    # Mail template variables
    @user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    @token = token

    mail(:to => to_email,
       :subject => MAILER_SUBJECTS_WELCOME,
       :template_path => "user_mailer",
       :template_name => "welcome_email")
  end
end
```

Then you can just access them in your email template using `<%= @user %>` and `<%= @token %>`

Comment: This has always been the case even prior to Rails 5.

Answer (score -1):

You **can** actually use the locals option with mail, it's just a bit confusing and inconsistent as to how.

Once you use `:locals` you can then access these locals in the mail template using instance variables, e.g.

```
:locals => { :name => 'Jane' }
```

and then in the template

```
Dear <%= @name %>,
```

Comment: Of course! This would have been tested back on Rails 2 though, something might have changed since then.

Comment: This doesn't work in Rails 4.2. I wouldn't expect it to based on the other answers.

Comment: Might be best to say what version of Rails this works with in the answer.